# Cypher UNION query

Tags: neo4j, union, cypher

I have the simple following graph:
http://console.neo4j.org/?id=v0cvwn

And I wonder why the following query:

```
 START n=node(2) 
 match n-[:KNOWS]-node 
 return node.name as name 
 UNION 
 START n=node(2) 
 match n-[:ACTS_IN]-node 
 return node.name as name
```

throws an exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Can't profile the same pipe twice
at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.profiler.Profiler.decorate(Profiler.scala:47)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.Pipe$class.createResults(Pipe.scala:35)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.NullPipe$.createResults(Pipe.scala:47)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:61)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:61)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:61)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.UnionIterator.loadNextIterator$1(UnionIterator.scala:60)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.UnionIterator.step$1(UnionIterator.scala:68)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.UnionIterator.stepIfNeccessary(UnionIterato
```

**Couple of questions regarding UNION:**

Is it possible to perform another final match clause on all the data which was accumulate in the result set as a result from the UNION in previous sub-queries?

Is it possible to perform an order by on that data?

Thanks.

Comment: Though this doesn't directly answer your question, I just wanted to mention that your query could be re-written without a `UNION`. Just use the first half of the query only, and use this for your MATCH: `n-[:KNOWS|ACTS_IN]-node`

Comment: Yep I know just a simple use case to try the UNION.. 10x any way

Answer (score 2):

According to these github comments, `UNION` is only support in version 2.0 or higher.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/125